# "FATAL: Module 88x2bu not found in directory /lib/modules/5.8.0-45-generic" when I do "modprobe 88x2bu"

Tags: modprobe

Helo i've been trying for many days,, but Im done I recognize I need a hand from the experts guys..

I purchased a cudy AC1300 wireless Dual Band USB adapter. and I found the right driver RTL8812BU due when I did lsusb I got

"Bus 003 Device 008: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC"

so I follow the instructions on README file

*sudo apt update
sudo apt -y install dkms git bc
git clone https://github.com/fastoe/RTL8812BU.git
cd RTL8812BU
VER=$(sed -n 's/\PACKAGE_VERSION="(.*)"/\1/p' dkms.conf)
sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
sudo reboot*

but in previous step before last step when I type
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
I got
modprobe: FATAL: Module 88x2bu not found in directory /lib/modules/5.8.0-45-generic

I use  Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS kernel ver.
Linux wc4u-HP-ProDesk-600-G1-SFF 5.8.0-45-generic #51~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 23 13:46:31 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

please HELP

Comment: `dkms status`  please maybe dkms failed.

Comment: Possibly you need to delete previous kernel files with cfg80211, then reinstall the driver.
Had the same error when installing the 88x2bu driver for rtl8812bu chipset / WLAN Usb Stick Cudy AC1300 on Linux Mint 21 with kernel. Did a kernel update a while before. Tried to fix the error by deleting cfg80211 files of previous kernel, and then recompiling the driver, but deleted too much. In the end i installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, there the driver worked for me.